# How to extract in python3 a signle value from json key with multiple values?

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
import json
person = '{"name": "Bob", "languages": ["Italian", "English", "Fench"], "location": "Naples"}'
person_dict = json.loads(person)
print(list(person_dict.values())[1:1])
```

Hi guys i've a little issue handling json value in py3.
The question is simple.. considering the code above, how i can extract only 'Italian' value from 'languages' key?

The code is surely wrong because it give nothing:

```
[]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

The imported pkgs:

```
from urllib3 import PoolManager, request
import certifi
import json2
```

the right api output in json format:

```
{
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "AUCTION1": {
            "asks": [
                [
                    "281.00000",
                    "0.163",
                    1609860353
                ]
            ],
            "bids": [
                [
                    "277.60000",
                    "0.100",
                    1609860353
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the function where i've the issue:

```
p_urll = PoolManager(ca_certs=certifi.where())
p_req = "https://api.auctionsite.com/0/public/Depth?pair=AUCTION1&count=1"
p_api_req = p_urll.request('GET', p_req)
p_api_res = json2.loads(p_api_req.data.decode('utf-8'))
print(p_api_res['result']['AUCTION1']['asks'][0])
```

It's not simple like the 1st example.. my fault..
Using [0] the code will give this result:

```
['26098.60000', '0.781', 1609861809]
```

i need only the auction price, so the 1st "asks" value (this "281.00000" without quotes)

Comment: you can access the langagues value using its key, this gives a list, then use list index to get the first item in the list `print(person_dict['languages'][0])`

Comment: sorry @ChrisDoyle the example used is not right. I've edited the question post ad now it's relly detailed.

Comment: asks is a list of list, not a single list. So you would need to use `print(p_api_res['result']['AUCTION1']['asks'][0][0])`

Comment: OMG! Thnx @ChrisDoyle ... wher's my brain?